# Strictly nondecreasing permutations of numbers

Tags: permutations

Suppose I have a 6 digit lock that accepts 0-9 as inputs for the 6 slots.

And I was told that the numbers in order from left to right are never less than the number to their left.
so 0,0,0,0,0,0 would be valid but 0,1,2,3,2,9 would not.

I tried to brute force it by looking for a pattern in increasing the number of slots on the lock.
If it allowed a single digit, 10 passwords.
if it allowed 2 digits, 55 passwords (I think)

10 that start with 0,

9 that start with 1,

8 that start with 2,

ect.

10+9+8+...+3+2+1=55

3 gets a lot bigger, 100 that start with 0, then 9 that start with "1,1" 8 that start with "1,2" but from there I get lost with my counting and its going to be a huge nightmare when I get up to 6.

Please tell me there is a better way!
Thank you.

Comment: The two examples of valid/invalid patterns seem to be switched....

Comment: @GregMartin 
Im not sure they are? the sequence has to be non-decreasing, so 0,0,0,0,0,0 should be valid since each number is not less that the number it follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "stars and bars" problem.  If you know how many examples of each digit appear in your number, the non-decreasing condition forces a unique solution.  So you need to know how many solutions there are to:

$$\sum_{k=0}^9 x_k=n,$$

where $x_k$ is the number of times the digit $k$ appears in your number, and $n$ is the length of your number.  That number is $\binom{n+9}{9}$.

Comment: I've elaborated in my answer.  Yes, for a $6$-digit password there are $\binom{15}{9}$ solutions.

Comment: Non-decreasing is a pretty strong condition.

Comment: Yeah it seems so!

Comment: Look at it this way:  For each combination of $6$ unique digits, $1$ permutation of those digits works and $719$ do not.

Comment: Correct, it does.  It corresponds to $x_1=6$ and all other $x_k=0$.

Comment: Thanks again! I think I'm starting to get it